# Sounds over something

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

> Sometimes all you could hear were the flat, hard, packing ***sounds
>   over*** the yelling. (A line from Fight Club)

What does "over" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) gives definition 3 for the adverb "over" as: "above".

I didn't readily find a definition of "over" that specifically pertained to sounds or hearing, but we often (at least in English -- is this different in other languages?) identify sound levels with physical heights:

> "The noise level was so **high**, I couldn't hear myself think."
>
> "We had to shout so that we could be heard **above** the roaring of the
>   waterfall."
>
> "The **low** murmur of the monks' chanting was always there, **beneath** the
>   sounds of our everyday activities."
>
> "To calculate the minimum detectable signal we first need to establish
>   the noise **floor** in the receiver."
>
> "Turn **up** the music!"

So your example just means that the flat, hard, packing sounds could be heard because they were louder than the yelling. Their sounds were at a level **above** that of the yelling.

Comment: In my language, we also use physical heights to identify different levels of sounds. Thanks.